# How can I achieve filterable or parameterizable queries on ADO dashboards?

Tags: azure-devops

I am part of a workgroup who uses a single project in ADO, but each employee is typically assigned user stories on multiple boards in the project. Since "Backlog" and "Sprint" views are specific to a single board, we wanted to provide a way for team members to see all assigned work across multiple boards. We created a dashboard, populated with "Assigned To = @Me" query widgets (along with other relevant time and scope parameters), so that a single dashboard would give individualized views for all employees.

We would like to take this same dashboard and have it be "filterable" by employee for use in sprint review -- i.e. keep the same layout with the same information but adjustable on the fly to any given employee. This would mimic the filtering functionality of "Sprints" and "Backlog" views by "Assigned To."

The default Query widget doesn't look like it has any mechanisms to do this and I haven't found any other OOB widgets that do. Does anyone have any recommendations for approaching this task? Ideally we can use OOB widgets since installing extensions involves requesting a review and installation from our org's admin, which we only want to do as a last resort.

One workaround I can see would be to copy the dashboard and queries, and change them to be per-employee instead of "@Me," meaning that the management team would flip through dashboards instead of adjusting parameters on a single dashboard. But we're hoping there's a simpler way with not as much overhead.